# sql server date format

Tags: sql, sql-server

how to get date in this format: `12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM`

i am trying it like this, but not finding any proper format solution.

```
select convert(varchar(100), getdate(), 103)
```

edited:

```
SELECT DISTINCT U.FirstName,U.LastName, U.UserId,    
dbo.GetCity(ES.UserID) as City, dbo.GetState(ES.UserID) AS State,    
dbo.GetSchool(ES.UserID) as School, R.RoleName as RoleName    
FROM [3rdi_EventParticipants] as EP    
Inner Join [3rdi_EventSignup] as ES on EP.SignUpID=ES.SignUpID    
Inner Join Users U on ES.UserID= U.UserId
Inner Join [UserRoles] UR ON U.UserId=UR.UserId
Inner Join [Roles] R on UR.RoleID= R.RoleID        
WHERE EP.PlaceStatus in(4, 8, 3)and EP.EventID=@ItemID and UR.RoleID NOT IN(0, 1, 2, 45, 27) 
and UR.ExpiryDate>(select CONVERT(varchar(10),getdate(),101) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(10),getdate(),108)+ ' ' +  right(convert(varchar(30), getdate(), 9), 2))
```

Comment: Are you certain that you want that formatting to happen within the database? Usually the better place is just before you show the data to the user.

Comment: That format is not listed in the CONVERT or CAST manual for SQL Server at all, been trying at it for the past few minutes. Not sure if you can go into that manipulation. What are using the date for?

Comment: I'm interested, is the ExpiryDate field a VARCHAR?  Seems strange to do date comparisons as strings...

Comment: @Dems :_ No, it's datetime format.

Comment: Then I'm not sure as to the point of your conversion?  Why not just use "And UR.ExpiryDate > getDate()"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format you're asking for isn't a [supported one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

You could probably construct it from two calls to `CONVERT` and a case expression:

```
select
   CONVERT(varchar(10),getdate(),101) + ' ' +
   CONVERT(varchar(10),getdate(),108) + ' ' +
   CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,getdate()) >= 12 THEN 'PM' ELSE 'AM' END
```

(Or, by preference, leave formatting of datetime values to whatever is calling the SQL Server)

---

If you want to perform a meaningful date comparison, you want both sides to be datetimes, not strings (Or if you're going to use strings, use a format such as 121, where a string comparison is meaningful).

Why is `UR.ExpiryDate` a varchar, and not a datetime column?

---

Assuming your regional settings can cope with an automatic conversion of the format you've specified to a datetime value, you'd be better writing the final line of your query as:

```
and CONVERT(datetime,UR.ExpiryDate)>getdate()
```

Comment: You could add `+ ' ' + right(convert(varchar(30), getdate(), 9), 2)` to get the AM/PM

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet - added - but are you getting why most people would recommend doing this formatting elsewhere now?

Comment: No i dont know?, but my query is some what where i need to fetch it from DB, I show you my query then please tell me what better i can do?see it above in edit part.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet - having seen your full query, why on earth do you want to use a string comparison for an expiry date? And the format you've picked is completely wrong for meaningful date comparisons - `select CASE WHEN '12/31/1996' > '02/28/2011' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` returns 1.

Comment: No, date format in DB is same as i asked you to tell me. Si in advance i know date format so why should i go for case , please make a sample query.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet - I'm trying to point out that comparing two dates as strings, in the format you've asked for, gives you meaningless results - it would say that 31st December 1996 occurs after today.

Comment: How come rally not getting, ur.expirydate is a date which will fall in next coming months, so i am doing right check using operator >, is'nt it?

Comment: doing select convert(datetime, ExpiryDate) from UserRoles  , gives me the same format as i told 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM, how come?

Comment: is getdate is perticular to server setting? do date time always give format yy/mm/dd hr:mm:sec